# MongoDB save pre-defined aggregation pipeline in server itself, and pass some sort of input variables

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a Python application (using pymongo) to run an aggregation pipeline on MongoDB server. The aggregation pipeline is quite large with around 18 stages and the final stage is a $merge -- so it doesn't return anything back to the Python client. Note that even though the pipeline is very large, it only accesses a few documents and it executes really fast.

From the Python client, I am calling this pipeline around a million times using multi-threading (with 32 threads). For each call, the only difference in the aggregation pipeline is in the first $match stage where the values of the fields change. In the sample code below, only parameters that change in each call in `var-list1`, `var2`, and `var3`.

```
pipeline = [
    {
        '$match': {
            'week': {'$in': <var-list1>},
            'eventCode': <var2>,
            'customer': <var3>
        }
    }, {
        ..... some long list of aggregation stages which is fixed...
    }, {
        '$merge': {
            'into': 'my_out_collection',
            'on': ['week', 'eventCode', 'customer'],
            'whenMatched': 'replace',
            'whenNotMatched': 'insert'
        }
    }
]
```

My MongoDB server has the capacity to accept more parallel threads (based on disk and CPU usage metrics). However, I am not able to use this as my client's network-out traffic is hitting the ceiling. I suspect this is because the aggregation pipeline I am using is very big.

Does MongoDB support any ways of saving an aggregation pipeline in the server, with some placeholder variables, that can be executed by just passing in the variables?

MongoDB server version = 4.4
Pymongo = 3.10.1

Comment: You can save the pipeline by creating a View, but unfortunately there is no ability to include/use placeholders for the variables

Comment: Perhaps you could implement a service on your MongoDB server, or elsewhere, that would act as a "middle man" and have the same functionality as a stored procedure with parameters.  The client would send the parameters to the service and it would execute the pipeline, etc.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, thanks. Hope future versions of mongo will support server-side functions.

Comment: It seems MongoDB has decided, for the moment, to not fully integrate that feature.  However, it seems important enough that MongoDB has [Atlas Functions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/functions/), but I could only find it on that platform.